# How do we insert new elements in an empty object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How does this `record[field]` line actually mean here...

```
record[field] = parseInt( $('input#'+field).val() );
```

is it inserting the int value in the empty object record in a new name-value field...if yes then can we do this using dot notation as well...here is the full code

```
  var fields = ['id', 'name', 'subject', 'theory', 'practical'];
            var record = {};

            for (var index in fields) {

                var field = fields[index];

                if (field == 'id' || field == 'theory' || field == 'practical')
                    record[field] = parseInt( $('input#'+field).val() );

                else
                    record[field] = $('input#'+field).val();

            }
```

Comment: `hen can we do this using dot notation as well` No, since `field` is a variable. Using dot notation you can only use static string as key name

Comment: I lost something? Where is the question?

Comment: hahaha...its right there @JoséM.Carnero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No dot notation wont work

record is an object/map

using record[field] you are adding an entry to object with key as field.

Comment: okay...so the array has 5 values...so according to my code, only the INT values of the id , theory and practical values will be added to  record ??

Comment: subject and name would also get added here, because your else part has the same assignment too